# Correctly exporting React app for use through CDN

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to bundle a React app in a single JS file, so that I can load it from a HTML file.

1.) Bundling it in one file:

`webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require("path");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const glob = require("glob");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "bundle.js": glob
      .sync("build/static/?(js|css)/*.?(js|css)")
      .map((f) => path.resolve(__dirname, f)),
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "build/static/js/bundle.min.js",
    library: "App",
    libraryTarget: "umd",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [new UglifyJsPlugin()],
};
```

2.) Using the basic create-react-app defaults, only change is here in `src/index.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";

module.exports = {
  init: () =>
    ReactDOM.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>,
      document.getElementById("root")
    ),
};

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

3.) On my mock CDN I have a helper loader file (`/loader`):

```
function loadScript(url, callback) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";

  if (script.readyState) {
    //IE
    script.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (script.readyState == "loaded" || script.readyState == "complete") {
        script.onreadystatechange = null;
        callback();
      }
    };
  } else {
    //Others
    script.onload = function () {
      callback();
    };
  }

  script.src = url;
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

And the bundled JS file containing the React app is served from `/js`.

4.) Then finally in some other HTML file (`index.html`):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello I am a webpage</h1>
    <body>
      <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
      <div id="root"></div>
      <script
        type="text/javascript"
        src="http://localhost:5004/loader"
      ></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        loadScript("http://localhost:5004/js", function () {
          console.log({ App });
          App.init({
            config: {
              name: "Colin",
            },
          });
        });
      </script>
    </body>
  </body>
</html>
```

### The Issue

The code seems to load fine, but the issue is that the App contains nothing, so `App.init` is undefined.

How can I export the App correctly?

Comment: Hi. Finally have you done this ? )